# why my image and first name disappears in this code?

Tags: php, image

This is my foreach function

```
<? foreach($Selected as $row)
     $value = $row['dPath'];
     $imgp =  base_url()."images"."/".$value;
{?>


<td>
  <?=$row['dFrindName'].'</br>';?>
  <?php */?> <img src="<?=$imgp ?>" name="b1" width="90" height="80" border="0"/>
</td>
<? }}?>
Print_r($Selected);
results in `Array ( [0] => Array ( [dFrindName] => chandruCP 
                    [dPath] => m11on.gif ) [1] => Array ( [dFrindName] => udaya 
                    [dPath] => logo.jpg ) )`
```

but only my last value of the array is displayed on image
I can get the name udaya and   logo.jpg  on the screen
 But i cant get chandruCP and m11on.gif
why it is so how can i get all the values and image on scrren

Comment: looks like your code is missing the brace for foreach in the first line. is this a typo here or in your code?

Comment: pinaki is saying that directly after foreach($Selected as $row) you need {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. The opening bracket `{` of your foreach is in the wrong place.
2. You have a random closing comment in the middle of your code
3. You are using invalid HTML, the correct way to write a self-closing is `<br />`

Here is your code rewritten to correct these errors, it should produce what you are trying to achieve:

```
<?
foreach ($Selected as $row) {
  $imgp =  base_url()."images"."/".$row['dPath'];
?>
  <td>
    <?=$row['dFrindName'];?><br />
    <img src="<?=$imgp;?>" name="b1" width="90" height="80" border="0" />
  </td>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I think I got it

```
    <? 
    foreach($Selected as $row) {
        $value = $row['dPath'];
        $imgp =  base_url()."images"."/".$value;
    ?>  
        <td>
          <?=$row['dFrindName']."</br>";?>
          <img src="<?=$imgp; ?>" name="b1" width="90" height="80" border="0"/>
        </td>
<?

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ($Selected as $sel) {    
    echo "$sel->dpath"; 
}
```

Comment: @ SANTANA Message: Trying to get property of non-object
This is the result